# Element-wise manipulation of a two dimensional list in python

Tags: string, multidimensional-array, python-3.6, win32com

I am writing a script to find meeting time for three people. I manage to get their Free/Busy status encoding in a binary format with 0 being free and 1 being busy in increment of 30 minutes for the next three days. I grouped their status by day into a dictionary format as below.

```
print(date_schedule)
{'Monday, 2020-02-03': ['000000000000000000101101001110110000000000000000',
  '000000000000000000001111011100001100000000000000',
  '000000000000000011110100011000110000000000000000'],
 'Tuesday, 2020-02-04': ['000000000000000000100010000000000000000000000000',
  '000000000000000000001111001000110000000000000000',
  '000000000000000011111000111100101000000000000000'],
 'Wednesday, 2020-02-05': ['000000000000000000111000000000000000000000000000',
  '000000000000000001001100110000000000000000000000',
  '000000000000000000111100000001001000000000000000']}
```

**Goal:** Translate those **0** into a block of thirty minutes intervals.

```
For Example: 00:00----00:30
             00:30----01:00
                   ...
             23:30----24:00
```

Attempted:

```
#Separate the code into a two dimensional list
schedule = date_free.values()

#Append the block to a new list.
free = []
for value in schedule:
   for v in value:
       for idx, time in enumerate(v):
           if time == '0':
                idx = idx/2
                end = idx + 0.5
                #5 slots, and two decimals
                idx = '{:05.2f}'.format(idx).replace('.50','.30').replace('.',':')
                end =  '{:05.2f}'.format(end).replace('.50','.30').replace('.',':')
                free.append((idx + '----' + end))
```

**Problem:** *free* has 372 elements and I don't know how to make it become a two-dimensional-list structure as it was before in *schedule* (because the number of 0 is different for each v). Is there a way to not creating a new list but directly apply the above logic element-wise to *schedule*?

**Bonus question**: I have not gotten there yet, but my next goal is to find the intersection of those 30 time block for each day as demonstrated in the **random** example below. If you have any suggestions, please let me know

```
print(date_time_final)
{'Monday, 2020-02-03': ['08:00----08:30','09:30----10:00','12:00----12:30'],
'Tuesday, 2020-02-04' : ['09:00----09:30','10:30----11:00','13:00----13:30','14:00----14:30']
'Wednesday, 2020-02-05' : ['07:00----07:30','14:30----15:00','15:00----15:30','19:00----19:30']}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: When I execute the above code, I dont get 372 values, but just 12: A list with the string element  `'00:00----00:30'` 12x. A few assumptions I have to confirm: 1) I assume the 3 binary sequences for each day are the 3 different people's busy/free statuses? Secondly, I assume you want the list to show only those free times, where all 3 persons are free, and right now you just append the free time slots to a list, but I assume your problem is, that if the first person being parsed is free and the next is not, you also need to remove the item retroactively?

Comment: @tst: Yes, all your assumptions are correct. I ended up figure this out by writing a function to translate only the '0' into time block for each binary string and using the 'reduce' function from 'functools' module to find the intersection of those zero-time-blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you were looking for?

```
schedule = {'Monday, 2020-02-03': ['000000000000000000101101001110110000000000000000',
  '000000000000000000001111011100001100000000000000',
  '000000000000000011110100011000110000000000000000'],
 'Tuesday, 2020-02-04': ['000000000000000000100010000000000000000000000000',
  '000000000000000000001111001000110000000000000000',
  '000000000000000011111000111100101000000000000000'],
 'Wednesday, 2020-02-05': ['000000000000000000111000000000000000000000000000',
  '000000000000000001001100110000000000000000000000',
  '000000000000000000111100000001001000000000000000']}

combined = {}
for value in schedule:
    day = {}
    for v in schedule[value]:
        for idx, time in enumerate(v):
            idx = idx/2
            end = idx + 0.5
            #5 slots, and two decimals
            idx = '{:05.2f}'.format(idx).replace('.50','.30').replace('.',':')
            end =  '{:05.2f}'.format(end).replace('.50','.30').replace('.',':')

            if time == '0':
                try: #Only assigns "True" if value does not yet exist and is not already False
                    if day[idx + '----' + end] == False:
                        pass
                    else:
                        day[idx + '----' + end] = True
                except:
                    day[idx + '----' + end] = True
            elif time == '1':
                day[idx + '----' + end] = False
    combined[value] = day

for day in combined:
    print(day)
    for time_slot in combined[day]:
        print("Time slot %s is free = %s" % (time_slot, str(combined[day][time_slot])))
```

Instead of lists, I used dictionary format to sort by day and by time slot, maintaining every time slot on record, but giving them a boolean value to determine if its free or not. (True == free, False == busy)
That way you can do whatever you like with the output.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for except it is solved in a different way. The thought of nested dictionary never crossed my mind. Thank you for showing me this. I do have a few questions, what exception are you catching? Can you explain how do you check if time == '0' not yet exist. Thank you!

Comment: Also, why do you need the try and except block inside the if statement? why can't you just directly set day[idx + '----' + end] = True if time == '0' and day[idx + '----' + end] = False if time == '1'

Comment: The exception I am trying to catch is KeyError. If the time == 0 and its the first time you enter the loop, the if statement checking for the value of the key will throw an exception, because the Key doesnt exist yet.